# Play framework on aws ec2 - HTTP port settings

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, playframework-2.0

i´ve been trying for days now to start a poorly documented play application (helping out friends) on aws ec2 as a complete play and bash-rookie and finally managed to start it; but not listening on port 8080, as in the playShop.sh file declared, but on a random port (8081) as 8080 threw an "already in use"- exception.

playShop.sh (with changed port):

> sudo nohup ./start -Dconfig.file=/home/ec2-user/prod.conf -Dhttp.port=8081 -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.1 &

start

> ## !/usr/bin/env sh
>
> exec java $* -cp "`dirname $0`/lib/*" play.core.server.NettyServer `dirname $0`

So far so good! But how can i access this now through the web browser? When i call the public DNS i run into a standard welcome page. I tried to set security group settings (quicklaunch1-->inbound) on that port and also played with load balancer-->listeners, but nothing really helped.

This seems to be the last step of a long journey and any help so welcome!
Thanks.

edit:
this is what nohup.out logged on these two ports:

```
    Play server process ID is 1593
[[37minfo[0m] play - Application started (Prod)
Oops, cannot start the server.
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /127.0.0.1:8080
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:298)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer.<init>(NettyServer.scala:63)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:132)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$5.apply(NettyServer.scala:162)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$5.apply(NettyServer.scala:161)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:161)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:137)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.bind(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:138)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleServerSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:90)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:64)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.bind(Channels.java:569)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:187)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap$Binder.channelOpen(ServerBootstrap.java:343)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelOpen(Channels.java:170)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.<init>(NioServerSocketChannel.java:80)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(NioServerSocketChannelFactory.java:158)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(NioServerSocketChannelFactory.java:86)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:277)
    ... 7 more
Play server process ID is 1650
[[37minfo[0m] play - Application started (Prod)
[[37minfo[0m] play - Listening for HTTP on port 8081..
```

.

Comment: are you using play 1.x  or play 2.x ?

Comment: is play 2.x i think (oct 2012 version?); but def not the latest one

Answer (score 0):

> So far so good! But how can i access this now through the web browser?
>   When i call the public DNS i run into a standard welcome page. I tried
>   to set security group settings (quicklaunch1-->inbound) on that port
>   and also played with load balancer-->listeners, but nothing really
>   helped.

When you hit a domain name with a web browser, it by default attempts to connect to port 80. To get around this, you have to access it like:

```
http://myserver.com:8081/
```

Which is difficult on users. To get around this, the recommended route is to have a proxy server to handle standard requests from clients which listens on port 80 and forwards requests to the application server (the play server) as needed. I usually recommend nginx for this, and the play framework homepage has a [basic guide for setting it up](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/HTTPServer). In your case it would be something like:

```
http {

  proxy_buffering    off;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   X-Scheme $scheme;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;

  upstream my-backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
  }

  server {
    server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) https://www.mysite.com$1 permanent;
  }

  server {
    listen               443;
    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/my_ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/my_ssl.key;
    keepalive_timeout    70;
    server_name www.mysite.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://my-backend;
    }
  }
}
```